# Get text between two characters

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, regex-greedy

I have a plain text file like below:

```
"sample1@gmail.com"
"sample2.test@gmail.com"
"sample3.test.test2@gmail.com"
```

and so on...

Now using Powershell I am trying to read line by line this plain text file and read the email without double quotes and add it to an array list:

```
$arrayListEmails = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$regex = '"([^/)]+)"'
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\temp\emailsList.txt") | Where-Object {$_ -match $regex} | ForEach-Object {
    write-host "email: $_"
    $arrayListEmails.Add($_) > $null
}
```

I don't know why but after executing above block of code I get email with double quotes, this is the output:

```
email: "sample1@gmail.com"
email: "sample2.test@gmail.com"
email: "sample3.test.test2@gmail.com"
```

and so on...

But I want the following (emails without double quotes):

```
email: sample1@gmail.com
email: sample2.test@gmail.com
email: sample3.test.test2@gmail.com
```

It seems like regex is taken the double quotes....

Comment: if you use `.Trim('"')` on each line you will get the line **_without_** the leading/trailing characters in the trim string. in this case it will remove the leading and trailing double quotes. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Else you can do it (import-csv remove double-quote on columns):

```
$Yourlist=import-csv "C:\temp\emailsList.txt" -Header Email
$Yourlist | %{ "email : {0}" -f $_.Email }
```

Comment: I like this solution. No need to use extra functions like trim, replace...

Answer (score 0):

Because you emails have quote :)  Try this

```
write-host ("email: " + $_.Replace('"', ""))
$arrayListEmails.Add($_.Replace('"', "")) > $null
```

Comment: Yes, my emails have quotes within plain text file. For this reason I use a regex to eliminate them from the beginning and from the end of each email read before storing it in the array list but it seems regex also gets the quotes instead of ignoring them.

Comment: your regex (if it was correct) dont eliminate quotes but filtre only your list and then you emails will be present into your final list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this regex could help you:

```
"([^/\)]+?)"
```

You have to use the group `$1` to get the value that you want. That's the email without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

there is a remarkably simple way to clean away leading and trailing characters from a string. use the `.Trim()` string method. [*grin*] it will remove each character in the trim list from the ends of the target string.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
"sample1@gmail.com"
"sample2.test@gmail.com"
"sample3.test.test2@gmail.com"
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$DeQuotedEmailList = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    # the trim string is <single><double><single> quotes
    #    it will remove any leading and/or trailing double quotes
    $IS_Item.Trim('"')
    }

$DeQuotedEmailList
```

output ...

```
sample1@gmail.com
sample2.test@gmail.com
sample3.test.test2@gmail.com
```